# Google Sheets: How to Move Data Between Sheets based on Text and Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have three sheets that I want to transfer rows of data between them based on certain conditions. From sheet1 to sheet2 based on a text string, and from sheet2 to sheet3 based on the difference between today's date the inputted date. However my attempts have been pretty fruitless thus far.

I want to move data from sheet1 to sheet2 based on whether column 'P' reads as 'Completed' or 'Thrown Out'. I also wanted to record the date it was changed to either of the above choices in column 'O'.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var c = ss.getSheetByName("Case Logs");
  var r = ss.getSheetByName("Recent Cases");
  var data = c.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(x) {return x[16];});
  var numColumns = c.getLastColumn();
  var current = new Date();


  for (var i= data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(["Completed"].indexOf(data[i])>-1) {
        var row = i+1;
        var target = r.getRange(r.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        c.getRange('O').setValue(current);
        c.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
        c.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();
        c.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearNote();
     }
    if(["Thrown Out"].indexOf(data[i])>-1) {
        var row = i+1;
        var target = r.getRange(r.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        c.getRange('O').setValue(current);
        c.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
        c.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();
        c.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearNote();
    }
  }
}
```

For the second condition, I wanted to move rows from sheet2 to sheet3 based on if the date listed in column 'O' is greater than or equal to a four months difference to the current date.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getSheetByName("Recent Cases");
  var a = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Cases");
  var data = r.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(x) {return x[16];});
  var numColumns = r.getLastColumn();
  var TIME_FRAME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 120;
  var now = new Date();
  var past = new Date(now.getTime() - TIME_FRAME);

  for (var i= data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (["**Column DATE**"].indexOf(logs[i])>-1 >= past){
      var row = i+1;
      var target2 = a.getRange(a.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      r.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target2);
      r.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();
      r.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearNote();
    }
  }
}
```

Though because I am literally slamming whatever bits of programming seem to be working, the entire thing is a mess. I do not know how to reference a specific cell within a column and confirm if it is a date, nor is the first onEdit section working anymore after I tried to have it input a date.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, it is a question/help request. Updated title to make it more clear. I do not know how to achieve what I am trying for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of suggestions for the first function:

Column P is 16 but arrays begin at zero and columns begin at one.

I'd replace this: `var data = r.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(x) {return x[16];});` with this `var data = r.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(x) {return x[15];});`

I'd replace this `if(["Completed"].indexOf(data[i])>-1)` with this: `if(data[i]=="Completed")`

Personally, I would reverse the order of your loops.  Your not deleting any lines and even if you were you can still keep track of how many you delete with one extra variable.

I wouldn't suggest running this on an onEdit() since your looping through all of the rows.  I would use the event object to determine which row that I'm on via `eventObject.range.rowStart` and deal with one line at a time.

- [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

If you wish to move data from one sheet to another and delete the old rows you can do something like this:

```
function moveAndDeleteRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet85');
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet86');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var n=0;
  var lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  var vA=rg.getValues().map(function(r){return r[15]});//this is equivalent to your get column P
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i]=='Complete' || vA[i]=='Thrown Out') {
      sh.getRange(i-n+1,1,1,lc).moveTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1));
      sh.deleteRow(i-n+1);
      n+=1;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the sort of function I'd use in an onEdit() it performs a similar process.  I set it up by putting a data validation in column P that's either 'Completed' or 'Thrown Out'.  So whenever you select one it gets moved to the other sheet and deletes the row that your on.

```
function moveData(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Case Logs') {return;}
  var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Recent Cases');
  if(e.range.columnStart==16) {
    if(e.value=='Completed' || e.value=='Thrown Out') {
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,e.range.getSheet().getLastColumn()).moveTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1));
      e.range.getSheet().deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves my first issues so that is awesome. Any idea on how to compare two dates for the second part? Moving them is set now.

Comment: I figured it out (based on an older post of yours funny enough). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545080/calculating-difference-between-two-dates-in-google-apps-script/47545363

So I guess thank you again!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.  Have a great evening.