# Trying to set a cell to the value of a function to get the difference of two times

Tags: google-apps-script

I was looking for a function to give the difference of two times and luckily one of the Users here had a great function that looked beautiful. [Code Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545080/calculating-difference-between-two-dates-in-google-apps-script/)

```
function getDaysHoursAndMinutes(){
  var hd=new Date('2017-11-21T20:23:26+0000').valueOf();
  var td=new Date().valueOf();
  var sec=1000;
  var min=60*sec;
  var hour=60*min;
  var day=24*hour;
  var diff=td-hd;
  var days=Math.floor(diff/day);
  var hours=Math.floor(diff%day/hour);
  var minutes=Math.floor(diff%day%hour/min);
  Logger.log('%s days %s hours %s minutes',days,hours,minutes);
}
```

So I tweaked it a little bit to more of my liking.

```
function getDaysHoursAndMinutes(t1,t2){
  var hd=new Date(t1).valueOf();
  var td=new Date(t2).valueOf();
  var sec=1000;
  var min=60*sec;
  var hour=60*min;
  var day=24*hour;
  var diff=td-hd;
  var days=Math.floor(diff/day);
  var hours=Math.floor(diff%day/hour);
  var minutes=Math.floor(diff%day%hour/min);
```

Created two variables that can be placed in the function.  I did this so I could make those variables `getValue(range)`
But perhaps I missed something or I don't understand the code well enough to know exactly how it works. Here is the format I was getting it for.

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}
function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue()
}
setValue('F' + passiveRow, getDaysHoursAndMinutes(getValue('D' + passiveRow),getValue('E' + passiveRow)));
```

passiveRow in this case is just a single number that is the row that matches some criteria. Let's say 2

So I thought just by getting the Values of D2 and E2 , values that look like this:`5/15/2019 21:17:15,    5/15/2019 21:18:33`, They would be implemented into the Formula correctly and the formula would return back into my setValue function.  So I logger.logged it and Logger.log(minutes=1) as it should.  I tried logging with a few other times and I got back numbers that were correct.  But inside of Row F, inside the correct box, it gives "undefined" instead of the number that the Logger.log in the time difference function is giving me.  I feel like it's a very obvious oversight that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: `getDaysHoursAndMinutes()` isn't [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)ing a value.

Comment: okay so I put ```return '%s days %s hours %s minutes ',days,hours,minutes;``` at the end of the getDaysHoursAndMinutes() function, but i kept getting numbers like 216:00:00 this Logger.log('%s days %s hours %s minutes %s seconds',days,hours,minutes,seconds) gives me back what I want it to look like, 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes.  So I don't know why the return isn't giving me back what the logger is showing.

Comment: Found out how to do it. ```return days+'days'+hours+'hours'+minutes+'minutes'+seconds+'seconds';```